# autocomplete json data - how can I use it in MVC3 Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When my jQuery autocomplete function gets json data items, how can I take the selected item and assign them to other textboxes in my DOM?

Do I wire up an event in the textbox?

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#CustByName").autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Cases/FindByName", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.CustomerName,
                            value: item.CustomerName,
                            id: item.CustomerID
                        }
                    })
                    );
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    });

});
```

and my controller action:

```
//Post: autocomplete customer names
    //[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FindByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
        {
        CustomerFind find = new CustomerFind();
        var result = find.FindCustomerByName(searchText, maxResults);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and my FindCustomerByName function

```
internal List<Models.Customer> FindCustomerByName(string searchText, int maxResults)
        {
        List<Models.Customer> result;

        using (cummins_sqldb dataContext = new cummins_sqldb())
            {

            result = (from c in dataContext.Customers
                      where c.CustomerName.Contains(searchText)
                      orderby c.CustomerName
                      select c).Take(maxResults).ToList();
            }
        return result;

        }
```

Comment: [Post some of the code you currently have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I edited my question to include code.

Comment: So am I understanding your question correctly that you want to take a value from one textbox and assign the value to another textbox?

Comment: I would like to take the json list that is return and auto populate some textboxes with relevant data.

Comment: I still cannot get this autocomplete code to work. Should I open another thread?